# Get specific data from API (angular)

Tags: html, json, angular, typescript, api

## Intro

I am trying to connect my website to GitHub API to get the most starred repos for the past 30 days, it then sends a response of a json file containing 100 repos, this part is okay in my application and it connects and receives the data correctly.

## Problem

The Problem is that it receives the json files with bunch of unwanted fields, I need only 5-6 fields and it contains nearly 25 so I want to map all these fields to my Typescript class. and I get this error message

```
Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays.
```

### Code

#### Typescript

```
getRepos(): Observable<Reop[]> {
    return this.http.get<Repo[]>(baseURL).pipe(catchError(this.processHTTPMsgService.handleError));
}
```

**Description**
This function in a service that will be called whenever the user needs to request a new page from the api and the "baseURL" is the URL of the new page and then returns it to the caller or returns an error after handling it if happened.

```
this.repoService.getRepos().subscribe((repos) => (this.repos = repos), errmess => this.errMess = <any>errmess);
```

**Description**
This will call the service and ask for the response then try to map it to the class or show a message if an error is received.
P.s: this is where the problem is I think, I can't map the response to my object.

```
export class Repo {
    name: string;
    username: string;
    avatar:string;
    description: string;
    stars: number;
    issues: number;
}
```

**Description**
This is the class of the wanted data in my project with all the needed values.
** Basic layout of the response **

```
{
  total_count: number;
  incomplete_results: boolean;
  items: {
      id: number;
      node_id: string;
      name: string;
      full_name: string;
      private: boolean;
      owner: {
        login: string;
        id: number;
        node_id: string;
        avatar_url: string;
       };
      html_url: string;
      description: string;
      fork: boolean;
      url: string;
      ...
      ...
      ...
      watchers: number;
      default_branch: string;
      score: number;
    }
}
```

**Description**
This is what the api sends, an array of 3 objects with the "items" object containing the and array of data from which I need only 5-6 fields.

## What's needed / expected

I want to filter the response to get the values that I need and that's it.

Comment: The error message comes from your template. You are trying use ngFor to iterate over an object - which is only possible if the object implements the iterable interface. Pretty sure you think what you are binding to is an array but it is actually not.